# Nature of vectors transforming to point in 2D and 3D space

Tags: linear-algebra

While learning linear algebra from 3b1b series, I came across following sentence at this [point](https://youtu.be/uQhTuRlWMxw?t=601):

> If a 2D tranformation squishes space onto a line, for example, 
>   there is a separate line in a different direction, full of vectors that get squished onto the origin. For example, in below diagram a transformation transforms all vectors on y-axis to the origin.
>   [image]

I have following doubts:

**Q1.** Does all vectors that get squished to a line need to lie on a single line? For example, cant there be any transformation which squishes all green vectors to green dot on x-axis? Or all vectors should lie only on single line only if they get squished to the origin, that this restriction exists only to those vectors which get transformed to origin?
[image]

**Q2.** The author further says:

> If a 3D transformation squishes space onto a plane, there is also a full line of vectors that land on the origin.

I guess for this also, those vectors need to lie on a single line if they transform to origin. If they transform to any other point, they may not lie on single line, right?

Comment: For Q1, I would say that the green arrows **do** lie on a single line. In particular, the tips of the arrows form a line.  Why do you say that the arrows do not lie on a single line?

Comment: By “transormation,” do you mean _linear_ transformation, or any transformation at all? There’s obviously some transformation that does what you’re asking about—you’ve drawn one—but there might not be any nontrivial _linear_ transformation with that property.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom author of video says "line full of vectors". I felt vectors means arrows from origin to arrow tip, i.e. whole arrow body should lie in same line. Also in diagram he showed whole body of all red arrows lie in same line. So I felt those green arrow bodies do not lie in same line. **Q3.** But do you mean to say, it's arrow head "points" that he is talking about and not about the whole body of arrow? But why? **Q4.** Can't there exist any transformation which can map multiple non collinear points to single point? **Q5.** If such transformation cannot exist, then why so?

Comment: @anir In my mind, there is no difference between a vector and a point. Therefore, a "line full of arrows" should mean the same thing as a "line full of points". Anyway, now I understand your perspective.

Comment: @amd yes, he defined linear transformation with two properties: all lines should remain line without getting curved after transformation and origin must remain fixed at its place after transformation. **Q6.** Why there cannot exist such linear transformation which can map all green vectors into single point? All those vectors will have form 
$\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{bmatrix}
$ with same $x$ & different $y$ & I felt transformation matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$ will map all of them to $\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$, that is same point. Right?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom was my perspective correct? I still feel Q3 through Q5 are still unresolved...

Comment: @anir Regarding 3: when you are talking about vectors that get squished to the origin, there is no difference between talking about arrows and talking about the tips of the arrows.  This changes when you talk about points/vectors that get squished to a point other than the origin. Regarding 4: such a linear transformation does exist

Comment: @anir so towards Q1, any "line full of vectors" (in your sense rather than mine) includes the origin. If that whole line gets squished to one point, then it must get squished to the origin (since linear transformations always send the origin to itself)

Comment: Those two constraints are not enough to force linearity. There are colineations that fix the origin that are not linear transformations.

Comment: @anir You are correct, your example is such a linear transformation. It is not clear to me that anybody was saying that such a linear transformation does not exist at any point.

Comment: Hi anir, do you know what the **kernel** and **image** of a linear transformation is? And that they are **subspaces**? How about the **rank-nullity theorem**? And **affine subsets**? Also, do you know that linear transformations **send 0 to 0**? I think these concepts would clarify your questions. You may not have encountered them yet, but I'd just like to point out what may be relevant, and maybe you'll be interested in checking them out or you'll encounter/learn them later.

Comment: @amd do mean to say that there can exist linear transformation that squish vectors with end points not lying on straight line into a point? Can you please give example?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom **(Q3)** why u said it doesnt matter whether "vector" refer to arrow-head end point or whole body when they are squishing to origin, but they are arrow bodies when they are getting squished to other points? **Q7.** Does ur comment "It is not clear .. at any point." not align with amd's "there might not be any nontrivial linear transformation with that property"? (sorry for follow up questions, but really need to have clear picture)(Continued..)

Comment: Now, after thinking a bit, feel vectors really mean "endpoints of arrowheads" (but need confirmation). **Qa.** In such linear transformation (reducing 2D space to a line), does all points ("not just the origin") in transformation output line are obtained by transforming all input points (input vector end points) in some straight line (not a curve or multiple distinct lines)? **Qb.** Cant there exist any linear transformation reducing 2D space to a line which transforms non co-linear points (input vector end points) to a point?

Comment: @anir Regarding the first question: I am saying that if the endpoints of a collection of vectors get squished to the origin, then the arrows themselves must also be squished to the origin. Regarding your second question, I see no clear connection between the two comments. Regarding Qa: the answer is yes. Regarding Qb: if a linear transformation outputs a point that is not the origin, then either only one vector gets sent to this point or the vectors that get squished to this point must be such that their endpoints form a line.

Comment: I am not able to get logical / visual / mathematical reason behind yours answers to Qa and Qb? Can you please also explain WHY of your answers to Qa and Qb?

Comment: No, I’m saying that there are transformations that map lines to lines and the origin to the origin, but are not linear transformations.